# jquery slider отправляет непонятные запросы серверу?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fastcgi, slider

Вот примерно такой код для slidera помещаю в скрипт.
И на сервер начинают отправляться дополнительно 2-3 запроса, видимо по загрузке изображений.

```
$( ).slider({
range: true,
min: первая_дата,
max: вторая_дата,
values: [ первая_дата, вторая_дата ],
slide: function
change: function
});
```

В переменные сервера попадают такие данные.

```
HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL=js/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_35_f6a828_500x100.png;
REQUEST_URI=images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_35_f6a828_500x100.png;

UNENCODED_URL=images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png;
HTTP_REFERER=http://ip/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css;
```

Вопрос в том, почему обработкой этих запросов занимается мой скрипт?
Здесь ведь запрашиваются изображения. 
Или ошибки могут быть в web сервере?

Comment: css же. Пытается себе грузануть ресурс (изображение). Вы же используете JqueryUi?

Comment: Ну да. Что значит пытается? то есть у него не получается?

Comment: @manking, если бы у него не получалось, например Firebug на вкладке "Сеть" отобразил бы ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понял в чём проблема. Довольно дурацкая.
Всё дело в модуле для iis modrewrite.
Ставил его чтобы чпу формировать. А там ссылка вида

```
1.1.1.1/index.php?file=catalog1/cat2/cat3
```

преобразуется в

```
1.1.1.1/catalog1/cat2/cat3
```

Обратное преобразование вначале проверяет существует ли файл или каталог по указанному адресу.
И если да то сервер сам обрабатывает его, а если нет то он преобразуется modrewrite обратно в

```
1.1.1.1/index.php?file=/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css
```

и передаётся скрипту.

А так как скрипт такой запрос обрабатывает и возвращает ответ, отладчики firebug не обнаруживают никаких ошибок.

А вот отключив modrewrite, firebug показал битые ссылки.

Comment: @manking, я рад, что Вы разобрались. Закрывайте вопрос